# Hello World on appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

I'm new to appcelerator. I just want to know how hyperloop works.

How can I put this in appcelrator? 
Or need to be javascript?

```
println(&quot;Hello world&quot;)
```

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you needed to write &quot; like that. I don't know Appcelerator but it looks like it's a cross-platform app framework, and most of the Google hits for "Appcelerator Hello World" (and there are plenty BTW) seem to be building a GUI, whereas you're trying to print a string e.g. to a console. Where are you expect it to print 'Hello World' to, exactly? Into a text box on the screen, or somewhere else?

Comment: Bad question im sorry, the good one is... can i write direct swift code in appcelerator? "println(&quot;Hello world&quot;)" is not nevcessary is just an example. thank you.

Comment: Right, sorry, you specifically meant the hyperloop bit. There's an 'edit' link at the bottom of your question: please use that to ask change this into the swift question instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Titanium had always been a platform for developing cross-platform native applications using the javascript language. Great cross-platform experience is achieved thanks to the Titanium SDK which covers a lot of native mobile elements. So you would for instance create a Textbox and the SDK will make this a native control on iOS and Android.

Hyperloop was created to allow developers call native classes, or combine native libraries in more ease (native libraries could be combined before Hyperloop days by creating a Native Titanium Module). But the great thing about Hyperloop is that you are accessing device level API but using javascript.

So, the above `println` command which is a C command won't work. Since it is javascript, if you would like to print output to console you could just use: `console.log("Hello World");`. Or, you could use the Titanium SDK `Ti.API.info("Hello World")`.

For more information check out the following links:

- https://www.appcelerator.com/mobile-app-development-products/hyperloop/
- https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Hyperloop_Programming_Guide
- https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Hyperloop_Programming_Guide